# Graphviz: Color only a field in a Record-based Node

Tags: graphviz

Is there a way to add color to only a field in a record-based node. Like in the following example, can the field struct2:f0 alone be in different color?

```
digraph structs {
node [shape=record];
struct1 [label="<f0> left|<f1> mid\ dle|<f2> right"];
struct2 [label="<f0> one|<f1> two"];
struct3 [label="hello\nworld |{ b |{c|<here> d|e}| f}| g | h"];
struct1:f1 -> struct2:f0;
struct1:f2 -> struct3:here;
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this is possible.

You may consider using **[HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/content/node-shapes#html)** - you should be able to do everything you can do with record-based nodes, and more.

From the above linked documentation page:

> The record-based shape has largely been superseded and greatly
>   generalized by HTML-like labels. That is, instead of using
>   `shape=record`, one might consider using `shape=none` and an HTML-like
>   label.

and

> Although HTML labels are not, strictly speaking, a shape, they can be
>   viewed as a generalization of the record shapes described above. In
>   particular, if a node has set its shape attribute to `none` or
>   `plaintext`, the HTML label will be the node's shape.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that this is 90's-era HTML, with font tags and table attributes. A second downside is that you need to mess with colspan/rowspan to distribute your record cells. But I don't think there's an alternative :-(

Comment: Yes, it's 90's-era HTML and our knee-jerk reaction is to despise it. But it's for a different purpose. For that purpose, it's modern Graphviz.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
  digraph G {
    "Record" [ label=<<table>
                          <tr>
                              <td>A</td>
                              <td bgcolor='#00CC11'>B</td>
                          </tr>
                       </table> 
                      >
             ];
  }
```