# Graphviz: How to add different font colors for a label name in dot

Tags: graphviz, dot

```
digraph d {
    node1 [shape=record, label="{ <f1>a | <f2>b | <f3>c }"]
}
```

I want to add a red color for `b` only, I tested `<f2> <font color='red'>b</font>` and it doesn't work. Could anyone show me an example of this?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but have a look at https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/tools/Graphviz/examples/index and at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765301/graphviz-dot-how-to-change-the-colour-of-one-record-in-multi-record-shape

Comment: @albert Thanks for your second link which solved my problem.

Comment: initial -> initial [label = "label",color=red, fontcolor=red];