# graphviz: change color of some nodes

Tags: svg, graphviz

I am using `NetworkX` to parse a graph and `graphviz` to represent that same graph as an `svg` file. I am trying to color each node of my graph based on the name of the node such as:

```
if node.name == 'abc':
  node.color = 'blue'
else:
  node.color = 'pink'
```

I was able to color every node of my graph with the same color and I am not able to set conditions to have different node colors based on my previous algorithm.
[image]

Based on this StackOverflow post, [Graphviz dot: How to change the colour of one record in multi-record shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765301/graphviz-dot-how-to-change-the-colour-of-one-record-in-multi-record-shape), it is probably not possible. But it I look at the `.dot` output file, each node as a color attribute so it should be possible to change it?

**graph.dot:**

```
digraph "" {
    graph [bb="0,0,61610,509.51",
        edge_default="{}",
        edges="{'arrowsize': '4.0'}",
        node_default="{}",
        rankdir=TD
    ];
    node [fillcolor=red,
        label="\N",
        shape=rectangle,
        style=filled
    ];
    "gold_adhoc_demand_review.countries"    [color=red,
        height=0.5,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="1010,234",
        table=countries,
        use_case=demand_review,
        width=3.1389,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location"    [color=blue,
        height=0.5,
        kind=core,
        pos="868,306",
        table=location,
        width=1.6389,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_demand_review.countries"    [pos="e,975.13,252.19 902.74,287.88 921.82,278.47 945.68,266.71 966.05,256.67"];
    "gold_adhoc_product_priorities.distribution_network"    [color=red,
        height=0.5,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="150,234",
        table=distribution_network,
        use_case=product_priorities,
        width=4.1667,
        zone=gold];
    "gold_core.location" -> "gold_adhoc_product_priorities.distribution_network"    [pos="e,300.22,251.11 808.82,299.62 708.56,290.46 498.65,271.06 310.31,252.13"];
    "gold_adhoc_global_supply_review.country"   [color=red,
        height=0.5,
        kind=adhoc,
        pos="1267,234",
        table=country,
        use_case=global_supply_review,
        width=3.4861,
        zone=gold];
...
```

**draw.py**

```
def draw_graph(networkx_graph):
    networkx_graph.graph['graph'] = {'rankdir': PYGRAPHIZ_RANKDIR}
    networkx_graph.graph['node'] = {'shape': PYGRAPHIZ_SHAPE_TYPE, 'fillcolor': 'red', 'style':'filled'}
    networkx_graph.graph['edges']={'arrowsize': PYGRAPHIZ_ARROW_SIZE}
    pygraphviz_graph = to_agraph(networkx_graph)
    pygraphviz_graph.layout("svg")
    pygraphviz_graph.draw("result.svg")
    print(pygraphviz_graph.graph_attr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you want to update is `fillcolor`, not `color`. `color` controls the border of a node.

(See the documentation at https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/fillcolor/)

Your logic would look like this to customize the fill color of individual nodes:

```
if node.name == 'abc':
  node.fillcolor = 'gold'
else:
  node.fillcolor = 'pink'
```

Note: you can use RGB color codes rather than names to give you more options, e.g.: `fillcolor = "#ffd700"`