# How do I style the ports of record based nodes in GraphViz?

Tags: graphviz, styling, dot

I'm feeding this simple input script defining [record based nodes](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#record) to dot in order to create a SVG from it (the SVG part actually doesn't matter):

```
graph mygraph{
  node [shape=record, fontsize=10, fontname=Arial];
  rankdir=TB;
  ranksep=0.5;
  rank=max;
  splines=true;
  overlap=false;
  mindist=0.2;
  "d1" [style=solid, label="{\N|{<0> 0|<1> 1}}"];
  "d2" [style=solid, label="{\N|{<0> 0|<1> 1|<2> 2|<3> 3}}"];
  "d1":0 -- "d2":0[color=blue, penwidth=3, tooltip="d1:0 -- d2:0", URL="#"];
}
```

This yields a graph where ports 0 of `d1` and port 0 of `d2` are connected by a blue spline:

[image: dot result]

Fine.

Now I have the need to **colorize the ports**. For example: port 1 of `d2` shall be green and port 2 of `d2` shall be orange. Or something.

How do I achieve this?

---

**Edit 1:** the solid frame around the nodes is important. I need it solid for some nodes, dashed for others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphviz: Color only a field in a Record-based Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009683/graphviz-color-only-a-field-in-a-record-based-node)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/content/node-shapes#html) give you a lot of flexibility in formatting labels. This code:

```
graph mygraph{
  node [shape=record, fontsize=10, fontname=Arial];
  rankdir=TB;
  ranksep=0.5;
  rank=max;
  splines=true;
  overlap=false;
  mindist=0.2;
  d1 [shape=none, margin=0, label=<
    <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <tr><td colspan="2">d1</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="0">0</td><td>1</td></tr>
    </table>>];
  d2 [shape=none, margin=0, label=<
    <table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <tr><td colspan="4">d2</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="0">0</td><td bgcolor="green">1</td><td bgcolor="orange">2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </table>>];
  d1:0 -- d2:0[color=blue, penwidth=3, tooltip="d1:0 -- d2:0", URL="#"];
}
```

Produces this graph:

[image]

Note the use of the `port` attribute to identify the port.

Comment: Looks promising. Why is the port 0 of d2 wider than the others? Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. I rendered it in PDF and blew it up and it is wider by the width of the border.